# Netbeans 11, how to generate a war file from a Springboot app

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, netbeans

I was studying Spring boot, now I want to get it to a server on my local machine. When researching for a way to deploy a Spring app the most common way was to generate a war file and deploy it with Tomcat. I've installed Tomcat 9. I want to generate a war file from my Springboot app. I am using Netbeans 11. which are the steps to do this? I've tried to build the app, I looked to look into the folder but there's no war to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to generate the war file.

```
<artifactId>artifact id</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>name</name>
```

I used the command mvn clean package afterwards

it will be under the target folder